# Controls and Map Center for OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I want to add more controls to myOl3ViewTemplate application. If you can help me add:

1. draw feature
2. delete feature
3. zoom[center] at a certain location

I looked at app.js and tried to add more controls but I couldn't get them to work. As for to zoom at a certain location I tried Bethlehem[South Africa] but the center goes to Congo I don't know why because these coordinates[-28.23333,28.3] says Bethlehem[SA] .

I would like you to help me on application launch to view only South-Africa and zoom at Bethlehem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me [recommend](http://christopherjennison.com/programming_tutorials/) this series of tutorials. The relevant parts for you will mostly be in [part 3](http://christopherjennison.com/openlayers-3-beginners-part-3/)

Here's an example of drawing a feature.

```
function startDraw(type) {
    if (draw != null) {
        cancelDraw();
    }

    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source:drawLayer.getSource(),
        type:type
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);

}
```

As far as centering over the Congo is concerned, I'm guessing it's an issue of map projections. I think you should be using spherical mercator projection, as explained in [part 1](http://christopherjennison.com/openlayers3-quickstart-tutorial/) of the tutorial near the end. Here's a website that will help you go from whatever projection you are using right now to [spherical mercator](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/).

In addition to this tutorial, I'd also recommend going through the [OL3 workshop](http://openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/) as well. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: The tutorials at http://christopherjennison.com/programming_tutorials/ are not available at the link mentioned, try also http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

Answer (score 0):

For "3. Zoom[center] at a certain location" have a look at this code:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';

// This will zoom to your provided location.
// Note: I am assuming you have a Map instance as *map*
function zoomToLocation(map, longlat, zoomLevel, duration = 1000) {
    const projectionCode = map.getView().getProjection().getCode();
    // Transforms a coordinate from longitude/latitude to a different projection.
    const center = fromLonLat(longlat, projectionCode);
    map.getView().animate({
      center,
      zoom: zoomLevel,
      duration,
    });
}
```

certain location is in a form of longitude latitude coodinates pair (Array) - `longlat`.

More detailed examples with `map.animate()` can be found in official OpenLayers examples page:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html